# Amazon Product API with meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, amazon-web-services, meteor

I would like to make requests for ItemSearch using Amazon Product Advertising API with  meteor.
http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/Associates/latest/prod-adv-api-dg.pdf
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/webstore_t_d/API/WebstoreAPI_SearchProductUsersGuide.pdf

Essentially, I would like the users on my web application to search and select books that they have read which will then  be displayed in their profile. 
As the user types in the  field, I would like the api to return a limited number of suggestions. When one item is selected, I would like to store the *title* and *author* of the book and *url* of the books' advertisement page on amazons website.

I have been sourcing the documents and branching out from the following two links. I am beginning to understand in an abstract way of how the error and data callbacks work. Everything I am reading is abstract.

I need to help in setting up the searchItem feature which falls under **Amazon Product Advertising API**
. I will limit the search index to the 'books' product category. According to amazon, I am effectively  advertising for amazon in my use case so I joined their affiliates program https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/
But really, my use case intensions are for my users to list books they have read on their profile page. I need to capture 3 data points (title, author, and,  url of the advertising page for the book on amazon.com).

Has anybody attempted to use this API? If so, please can you shed light on how you set up to make requests to the API in meteor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Amazon Product Advertising API** does not fall under **Amazon Web Services**, but instead, **Amazon Associates**.

The AWS SDK does not support non-AWS services (including other Amazon services), and likely never will. You'll need to find an entirely different package for hitting the Amazon Product Advertising API.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I was reading over the documents last night and what you are saying is correct. I have contacted their team after signing up to the affiliates programme. I shall update this question and links to relevant resources as I progress with this issue.